# Vaadin8 CKEditor how to get cursor position

Tags: ckeditor, vaadin8

How to know the cursor position in CKEditor with Vaadin 8? Our requirement is to insert an image in editor by knowing the cursor position. The user will be selecting an image name from the dropdown and we have to insert that image in the position where cursor is.